# Including DevTools in Spring Boot's JAR with Gradle during development

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I've been looking for an answer but pretty much everything I found so far is either outdated or didn't work. I'd like to include Spring DevTools inside my JAR so that I can use live reloading feature.

What I did so far;

1. Built a Docker image with `./gradlew bootBuildImage`.
2. Created a `docker-compose.yml` which uses this image.
3. Changed configuration in IntelliJ to use `org.springframework.boot.devtools.RemoteSpringApplication` as the main class.

[image: intellij configuration devtools]

However, when I change something and build the project I always get the same error:

```
Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected 404 NOT_FOUND response uploading class files
```

Do I need to change the way I build the image or apply some additional Gradle configuration for this to work? With Maven it was enough to just set `excludeDevTools` to `false` but looks like it doesn't work with Gradle.

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22533

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this in the `build.gradle.kts`;

```
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    classpath(configurations["developmentOnly"])
}
```